# Unable to extract SO's data dump file by Mac

Tags: macos, extract, 7zip

I run the following Gert's [extract command](https://serverfault.com/questions/3743/what-useful-things-can-one-add-to-ones-bashrc/3842#3842) to the [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/so-export-2009-06.7z.torrent) file which format .7z seems to be a problem:

```
extract () {
   if [ -f $1 ] ; then
       case $1 in
           *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf $1    ;;
           *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf $1    ;;
           *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1     ;;
           *.rar)       unrar x $1       ;;
           *.gz)        gunzip $1      ;;
           *.tar)       tar xvf $1     ;;
           *.tbz2)      tar xvjf $1    ;;
           *.tgz)       tar xvzf $1    ;;
           *.zip)       unzip $1       ;;
           *.Z)         uncompress $1  ;;
           *.7z)        7z x $1        ;;
           *)           echo "don't know how to extract '$1'..." ;;
       esac
   else
       echo "'$1' is not a valid file!"
   fi
 }
```

I run it to the dump file. I get

```
extract so-export-2009-06.7z       
extract:13: command not found: 7z
```

This suggested that I do not have 7z to extract files.
I installed the app p7zip by MacPorts unsuccessfully.
It did not start to act as 7z unzipper.

**How can you unzip SO's data dump?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

try using 7za instead of 7z as the executable name, as it appears that is what the port installs

so change the line

```
*.7z)        7z x $1        ;;
```

to

```
*.7z)        7za x $1        ;;
```

Comment: I have that in my PATH. echo $PATH gives me: /usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/misc-utils:/usr/local/screen-4.0.3:/usr/local/xsel-1.2.0:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH:/usr/bin/perl

Comment: @Thank you for your answer! --- It seems that the key in finding the solution was to google "p7zip" and then you noticed that it installed the app 7za.